# For each TabStripItem in Tabs I want the width to be defined by the length of it's text in label

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using the [`Tabs`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/tabs) component in Nativescript Vue and have set up a bunch of `tabStripItems` in `data` that renders each `TabStripItem` using `v-for`. I want the width of each `TabStripItem` to be defined by the length of the text in `Label`, as per [Google's Material Design Guideline](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-components%2Fassets%2F1pA2gYVY1WAw58epIs3rH8F6ABz5qu1uw%2Ftabs-scrollable-01.png).

```
<Tabs>
      <TabStrip class="tab-strip">
          <TabStripItem v-for="(item, index) in tabStripItems" :key="index" :width="item.text.length * 10">
             <Label :text="item.text"></Label>
          </TabStripItem>
      </TabStrip>
      ...
</Tabs>
```

I have tried out rendering each `TabStripItem` statically with an explict `width` attribute.

```
<Tabs>
    <TabStrip class="tab-strip">
      <TabStripItem width="80">
        <Label text="Flat"></Label>
      </TabStripItem>
      <TabStripItem width="160">
        <Label text="Visitors"></Label>
      </TabStripItem>
      <TabStripItem width="140">
        <Label text="Parking"></Label>
      </TabStripItem>
      <TabStripItem width="280">
        <Label text="Family Members"></Label>
      </TabStripItem>

    </TabStrip>
    ...
</Tabs>
```

The width of each `TabStripItem` is always proportionate to the length of the longest text, in this case "Family Members", consequently rendering the other items with a lot of white space.

How to achieve unequal widths for `TabStripItem`s?

Answer (score 0):

TabStripItem seems to have a parent wrapper inside TabBar, try this

```
 onTabsLoaded: function(event) {
            var tabs = event.object;
            if (tabs.android) {
                tabs.originalSetTabStripItems = tabs.setTabStripItems;
                tabs.setTabStripItems = function(items) {
                    tabs.originalSetTabStripItems.call(this,
                        items);
                    if (items && items.length) {
                        var tabsBar = this._tabsBar;
                        items.forEach((item, index) => {
                            var view = tabsBar
                                .getViewForItemAt(index);
                            var layoutParams = view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.weight = 0;
                            layoutParams.width =
                                android.widget
                                .LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                                .WRAP_CONTENT;
                            view.setLayoutParams(
                                layoutParams);
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=EZTW8a&v=1)